# Encrypt then decrypt pixels bits of image

Tags: python, cryptography

I want to encrypt an image by its bits (010101) of 128 length (i have to perform an algorithm on it), then save the new image. 
And read the encrypted image, then reverse back the bits and then save it again.

I have tried several methods:
base64 encode/decode: it works but the encrypted images is not viewable (corrupted header), but when I decrypt it, it back to normal again.

By using PIL library: reading the image data, change the pixel value, then created new image (image is viewable - one requirement is completed), but when I decrypt it, it is not coming back to its previous state.

example with PIL putpixel:

```py
def enc(original_name, encrypted_name):
    input_image = Image.open(original_name)
    data = input_image.load()
    output_image = Image.new(input_image.mode, input_image.size)

    for x in range(input_image.size[0]):
        for y in range(input_image.size[1]):
            r, g, b = data[x, y]
            r1 = int('{:08b}'.format(r)[::-1], 2)
            g1 = int('{:08b}'.format(g)[::-1], 2)
            b1 = int('{:08b}'.format(b)[::-1], 2)
            output_image.putpixel((x, y), (r1, g1, b1))

    output_image.save(encrypted_name)
    input_image.close()
    output_image.close()


def dec(encrypted_name, original_name):
    encrypted_image = Image.open(encrypted_name)
    data = encrypted_image.load()
    normal_image = Image.new(encrypted_image.mode, encrypted_image.size)

    for x in range(encrypted_image.size[0]):
        for y in range(encrypted_image.size[1]):
            r, g, b = data[x, y]
            r1 = int('{:08b}'.format(r)[::-1], 2)
            g1 = int('{:08b}'.format(g)[::-1], 2)
            b1 = int('{:08b}'.format(b)[::-1], 2)
            normal_image.putpixel((x, y), (r1, g1, b1))

    normal_image.save(original_name)
    encrypted_image.close()
    normal_image.close()


enc('images/lena.jpg', 'images/lena-enc.jpg')
dec('images/lena-enc.jpg', 'images/lena-dec.jpg')
```

example with putdata:

```py
def enc(original_name, encrypted_name):
    original_image = Image.open(original_name)
    encrypted_image = Image.new(original_image.mode, original_image.size)
    raw = list(original_image.getdata())
    eraw = []
    for px in raw:
        r, g, b = px
        r1 = int('{:08b}'.format(r)[::-1], 2)
        g1 = int('{:08b}'.format(g)[::-1], 2)
        b1 = int('{:08b}'.format(b)[::-1], 2)
        eraw.append((r1, g1, b1))

    encrypted_image.putdata(eraw)
    encrypted_image.save(encrypted_name)
    original_image.close()
    encrypted_image.close()


def dec(encrypted_name, original_name):
    encrypted_image = Image.open(encrypted_name)
    raw = list(encrypted_image.getdata())
    normal_image = Image.new(encrypted_image.mode, encrypted_image.size)

    eraw = []
    for px in raw:
        r, g, b = px
        r1 = int('{:08b}'.format(r)[::-1], 2)
        g1 = int('{:08b}'.format(g)[::-1], 2)
        b1 = int('{:08b}'.format(b)[::-1], 2)
        eraw.append((r1, g1, b1))

    normal_image.putdata(eraw)
    normal_image.save(original_name)
    encrypted_image.close()
    normal_image.close()


enc('images/lena.jpg', 'images/lena1.jpg')
dec('images/lena1.jpg', 'images/lena2.jpg')
```

Is there any way to get the viewable encrypted image that can be decrypted?

Comment: JPEG uses lossy compression.

Comment: Try a bitmap image instead, and try to only encrypt the pixels or dots themselves, not the header information.